# font-awesome not showing icons (only squares) with React and Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, font-awesome

I'm trying to use `font-awesome` with **React** and **Webpack**. I've installed font-awesome using npm:

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

I've configured `webpack` properly and I can see that `font-awesome` is being loaded by Webpack and bundled in my `bundle.js`:

```
   $ npm run hot

    > webpack-dev-server --inline --hot

     http://localhost:8080/
    webpack result is served from /dist
    content is served from D:\DEV
    webpack: wait until bundle finished: /dist/bundle.js
    Hash: 81a27e2b33864a94773b
    Version: webpack 1.14.0
    Time: 2909ms
                                     Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
      674f50d287a8c48dc19ba404d20fe713.eot   166 kB          [emitted]
      f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1.eot  20.1 kB          [emitted]
     fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff  23.4 kB          [emitted]
      e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512.ttf  45.4 kB          [emitted]
      89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg   109 kB          [emitted]
    448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2    18 kB          [emitted]
    af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e.woff2  77.2 kB          [emitted]
     fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad.woff    98 kB          [emitted]
      b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf   166 kB          [emitted]
      912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde.svg   444 kB          [emitted]
                                 bundle.js  1.83 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 1.74 MB [rendered]

   [0] multi main 52 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 3.97 kB {0} [built]
    [2] ./~/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
    [3] ./~/url/~/punycode/punycode.js 14.6 kB {0} [built]
    [4] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 251 bytes {0} [built]
    [5] ./~/url/util.js 314 bytes {0} [built]
    [6] ./~/querystring/index.js 127 bytes {0} [built]
    [7] ./~/querystring/decode.js 2.4 kB {0} [built]
    [8] ./~/querystring/encode.js 2.09 kB {0} [built]
    [9] ./~/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
   [10] ./~/ansi-regex/index.js 135 bytes {0} [built]
   [11] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 856 bytes {0} [built]
   [12] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/entry.js 244 bytes {0} [built]
   [13] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport-list.js 613 bytes {0} [built]
   [14] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/websocket.js 2.71 kB {0} [built]
   [15] ./~/process/browser.js 5.3 kB {0} [built]
   [16] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/event.js 2 kB {0} [built]
   [17] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/random.js 746 bytes {0} [built]
   [18] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/browser-crypto.js 438 bytes {0} [built]
   [19] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/url.js 975 bytes {0} [built]
   [20] ./~/url-parse/index.js 9.92 kB {0} [built]
   [21] ./~/requires-port/index.js 753 bytes {0} [built]
   [22] ./~/url-parse/lolcation.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
   [23] ./~/querystringify/index.js 1.3 kB {0} [built]
   [24] ./~/debug/browser.js 3.76 kB {0} [built]
   [25] ./~/debug/debug.js 4.1 kB {0} [built]
   [26] ./~/ms/index.js 2.33 kB {0} [built]
   [27] ./~/inherits/inherits_browser.js 672 bytes {0} [built]
   [28] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js 1.27 kB {0} [built]
   [29] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js 1.85 kB {0} [built]
   [30] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/browser/websocket.js 172 bytes {0} [built]
   [31] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xhr-streaming.js 1.25 kB {0} [built]
   [32] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/ajax-based.js 1.31 kB {0} [built]
   [33] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/sender-receiver.js 1.15 kB {0} [built]
   [34] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/buffered-sender.js 2.3 kB {0} [built]
   [35] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/polling.js 1.32 kB {0} [built]
   [36] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/xhr.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
   [37] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xhr-cors.js 343 bytes {0} [built]
   [38] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/browser/abstract-xhr.js 4.8 kB {0} [built]
   [39] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xhr-local.js 352 bytes {0} [built]
   [40] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/browser.js 560 bytes {0} [built]
   [41] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xdr-streaming.js 984 bytes {0} [built]
   [42] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xdr.js 2.46 kB {0} [built]
   [43] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/eventsource.js 766 bytes {0} [built]
   [44] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/eventsource.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
   [45] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/browser/eventsource.js 37 bytes {0} [built]
   [46] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/iframe-wrap.js 981 bytes {0} [built]
   [47] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/iframe.js 3.83 kB {0} [built]
   [48] ./~/json3/lib/json3.js 43.3 kB {0} [built]
   [49] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 43 bytes {0} [built]
   [50] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/version.js 26 bytes {0} [built]
   [51] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/iframe.js 5.06 kB {0} [built]
   [52] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/object.js 532 bytes {0} [built]
   [53] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/htmlfile.js 710 bytes {0} [built]
   [54] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/htmlfile.js 2.2 kB {0} [built]
   [55] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xhr-polling.js 894 bytes {0} [built]
   [56] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xdr-polling.js 712 bytes {0} [built]
   [57] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/jsonp-polling.js 1.02 kB {0} [built]
   [58] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/jsonp.js 5.57 kB {0} [built]
   [59] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/jsonp.js 2.46 kB {0} [built]
   [60] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/main.js 11.9 kB {0} [built]
   [61] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/shims.js 18.2 kB {0} [built]
   [62] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/escape.js 2.31 kB {0} [built]
   [63] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/transport.js 1.35 kB {0} [built]
   [64] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/log.js 450 bytes {0} [built]
   [65] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/event.js 477 bytes {0} [built]
   [66] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/location.js 177 bytes {0} [built]
   [67] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/close.js 295 bytes {0} [built]
   [68] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/trans-message.js 292 bytes {0} [built]
   [69] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/info-receiver.js 2.22 kB {0} [built]
   [70] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xhr-fake.js 456 bytes {0} [built]
   [71] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/info-iframe.js 1.52 kB {0} [built]
   [72] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/info-iframe-receiver.js 791 bytes {0} [built]
   [73] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/info-ajax.js 1.03 kB {0} [built]
   [74] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/iframe-bootstrap.js 2.9 kB {0} [built]
   [75] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/facade.js 723 bytes {0} [built]
   [76] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.85 kB {0} [built]
   [77] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 813 bytes {0} [built]
   [78] ./client/app.js 770 bytes {0} [built]
   [79] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
   [80] ./~/react/lib/React.js 2.69 kB {0} [built]
   [81] ./~/object-assign/index.js 2.11 kB {0} [built]
   [82] ./~/react/lib/ReactChildren.js 6.19 kB {0} [built]
   [83] ./~/react/lib/PooledClass.js 3.36 kB {0} [built]
   [84] ./~/react/lib/reactProdInvariant.js 1.24 kB {0} [built]
   [85] ./~/fbjs/lib/invariant.js 1.63 kB {0} [built]
   [86] ./~/react/lib/ReactElement.js 11.2 kB {0} [built]
   [87] ./~/react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner.js 623 bytes {0} [built]
   [88] ./~/fbjs/lib/warning.js 2.1 kB {0} [built]
   [89] ./~/fbjs/lib/emptyFunction.js 1.08 kB {0} [built]
   [90] ./~/react/lib/canDefineProperty.js 661 bytes {0} [built]
   [91] ./~/react/lib/ReactElementSymbol.js 622 bytes {0} [built]
   [92] ./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js 7.03 kB {0} [built]
   [93] ./~/react/lib/getIteratorFn.js 1.12 kB {0} [built]
   [94] ./~/react/lib/KeyEscapeUtils.js 1.29 kB {0} [built]
   [95] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponent.js 4.61 kB {0} [built]
   [96] ./~/react/lib/ReactNoopUpdateQueue.js 3.36 kB {0} [built]
   [97] ./~/fbjs/lib/emptyObject.js 458 bytes {0} [built]
   [98] ./~/react/lib/ReactPureComponent.js 1.32 kB {0} [built]
   [99] ./~/react/lib/ReactClass.js 26.5 kB {0} [built]
  [100] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTypeLocationNames.js 572 bytes {0} [built]
  [101] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMFactories.js 5.53 kB {0} [built]
  [102] ./~/react/lib/ReactElementValidator.js 8.32 kB {0} [built]
  [103] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook.js 10.4 kB {0} [built]
  [104] ./~/react/lib/checkReactTypeSpec.js 4.19 kB {0} [built]
  [105] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTypesSecret.js 442 bytes {0} [built]
  [106] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTypes.js 15.8 kB {0} [built]
  [107] ./~/react/lib/ReactVersion.js 350 bytes {0} [built]
  [108] ./~/react/lib/onlyChild.js 1.34 kB {0} [built]
  [109] ./~/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {0} [built]
  [110] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js 5.14 kB {0} [built]
  [111] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponentTree.js 6.27 kB {0} [built]
  [112] ./~/react-dom/lib/reactProdInvariant.js 1.24 kB {0} [built]
  [113] ./~/react-dom/lib/DOMProperty.js 8.24 kB {0} [built]
  [114] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponentFlags.js 429 bytes {0} [built]
  [115] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultInjection.js 3.5 kB {0} [built]
  [116] ./~/react-dom/lib/ARIADOMPropertyConfig.js 1.82 kB {0} [built]
  [117] ./~/react-dom/lib/BeforeInputEventPlugin.js 13.3 kB {0} [built]
  [118] ./~/react-dom/lib/EventPropagators.js 5.09 kB {0} [built]
  [119] ./~/react-dom/lib/EventPluginHub.js 9.11 kB {0} [built]
  [120] ./~/react-dom/lib/EventPluginRegistry.js 9.75 kB {0} [built]
  [121] ./~/react-dom/lib/EventPluginUtils.js 7.95 kB {0} [built]
  [122] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js 2.25 kB {0} [built]
  [123] ./~/react-dom/lib/accumulateInto.js 1.69 kB {0} [built]
  [124] ./~/react-dom/lib/forEachAccumulated.js 855 bytes {0} [built]
  [125] ./~/fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment.js 1.06 kB {0} [built]
  [126] ./~/react-dom/lib/FallbackCompositionState.js 2.43 kB {0} [built]
  [127] ./~/react-dom/lib/PooledClass.js 3.36 kB {0} [built]
  [128] ./~/react-dom/lib/getTextContentAccessor.js 955 bytes {0} [built]
  [129] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticCompositionEvent.js 1.1 kB {0} [built]
  [130] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticEvent.js 9.18 kB {0} [built]
  [131] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticInputEvent.js 1.09 kB {0} [built]
  [132] ./~/react-dom/lib/ChangeEventPlugin.js 11.1 kB {0} [built]
  [133] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactUpdates.js 9.53 kB {0} [built]
  [134] ./~/react-dom/lib/CallbackQueue.js 3.16 kB {0} [built]
  [135] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactFeatureFlags.js 628 bytes {0} [built]
  [136] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactReconciler.js 6.21 kB {0} [built]
  [137] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactRef.js 2.56 kB {0} [built]
  [138] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactOwner.js 3.53 kB {0} [built]
  [139] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactInstrumentation.js 601 bytes {0} [built]
  [140] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDebugTool.js 11.7 kB {0} [built]
  [141] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactInvalidSetStateWarningHook.js 984 bytes {0} [built]
  [142] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactHostOperationHistoryHook.js 736 bytes {0} [built]
  [143] ./~/fbjs/lib/performanceNow.js 845 bytes {0} [built]
  [144] ./~/fbjs/lib/performance.js 588 bytes {0} [built]
  [145] ./~/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js 9.45 kB {0} [built]
  [146] ./~/react-dom/lib/getEventTarget.js 1.01 kB {0} [built]
  [147] ./~/react-dom/lib/isEventSupported.js 1.94 kB {0} [built]
  [148] ./~/react-dom/lib/isTextInputElement.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]
  [149] ./~/react-dom/lib/DefaultEventPluginOrder.js 1.08 kB {0} [built]
  [150] ./~/react-dom/lib/EnterLeaveEventPlugin.js 3.16 kB {0} [built]
  [151] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticMouseEvent.js 2.14 kB {0} [built]
  [152] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticUIEvent.js 1.57 kB {0} [built]
  [153] ./~/react-dom/lib/ViewportMetrics.js 606 bytes {0} [built]
  [154] ./~/react-dom/lib/getEventModifierState.js 1.23 kB {0} [built]
  [155] ./~/react-dom/lib/HTMLDOMPropertyConfig.js 5.44 kB {0} [built]
  [156] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactComponentBrowserEnvironment.js 906 bytes {0} [built]
  [157] ./~/react-dom/lib/DOMChildrenOperations.js 7.67 kB {0} [built]
  [158] ./~/react-dom/lib/DOMLazyTree.js 3.71 kB {0} [built]
  [159] ./~/react-dom/lib/DOMNamespaces.js 505 bytes {0} [built]
  [160] ./~/react-dom/lib/setInnerHTML.js 3.86 kB {0} [built]
  [161] ./~/react-dom/lib/createMicrosoftUnsafeLocalFunction.js 810 bytes {0} [built]
  [162] ./~/react-dom/lib/setTextContent.js 1.45 kB {0} [built]
  [163] ./~/react-dom/lib/escapeTextContentForBrowser.js 3.43 kB {0} [built]
  [164] ./~/react-dom/lib/Danger.js 2.24 kB {0} [built]
  [165] ./~/fbjs/lib/createNodesFromMarkup.js 2.66 kB {0} [built]
  [166] ./~/fbjs/lib/createArrayFromMixed.js 4.11 kB {0} [built]
  [167] ./~/fbjs/lib/getMarkupWrap.js 3.04 kB {0} [built]
  [168] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMIDOperations.js 956 bytes {0} [built]
  [169] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js 38.5 kB {0} [built]
  [170] ./~/react-dom/lib/AutoFocusUtils.js 599 bytes {0} [built]
  [171] ./~/fbjs/lib/focusNode.js 704 bytes {0} [built]
  [172] ./~/react-dom/lib/CSSPropertyOperations.js 6.87 kB {0} [built]
  [173] ./~/react-dom/lib/CSSProperty.js 3.66 kB {0} [built]
  [174] ./~/fbjs/lib/camelizeStyleName.js 1 kB {0} [built]
  [175] ./~/fbjs/lib/camelize.js 708 bytes {0} [built]
  [176] ./~/react-dom/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js 3.02 kB {0} [built]
  [177] ./~/fbjs/lib/hyphenateStyleName.js 974 bytes {0} [built]
  [178] ./~/fbjs/lib/hyphenate.js 800 bytes {0} [built]
  [179] ./~/fbjs/lib/memoizeStringOnly.js 698 bytes {0} [built]
  [180] ./~/react-dom/lib/DOMPropertyOperations.js 7.61 kB {0} [built]
  [181] ./~/react-dom/lib/quoteAttributeValueForBrowser.js 700 bytes {0} [built]
  [182] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactBrowserEventEmitter.js 12.6 kB {0} [built]
  [183] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactEventEmitterMixin.js 959 bytes {0} [built]
  [184] ./~/react-dom/lib/getVendorPrefixedEventName.js 2.87 kB {0} [built]
  [185] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMInput.js 12.6 kB {0} [built]
  [186] ./~/react-dom/lib/LinkedValueUtils.js 5.15 kB {0} [built]
  [187] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactPropTypesSecret.js 442 bytes {0} [built]
  [188] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMOption.js 3.69 kB {0} [built]
  [189] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMSelect.js 6.81 kB {0} [built]
  [190] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMTextarea.js 6.46 kB {0} [built]
  [191] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactMultiChild.js 14.6 kB {0} [built]
  [192] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactComponentEnvironment.js 1.3 kB {0} [built]
  [193] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactInstanceMap.js 1.22 kB {0} [built]
  [194] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js 6.11 kB {0} [built]
  [195] ./~/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js 5.05 kB {0} [built]
  [196] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js 35.2 kB {0} [built]
  [197] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactNodeTypes.js 1.02 kB {0} [built]
  [198] ./~/react-dom/lib/checkReactTypeSpec.js 4.21 kB {0} [built]
  [199] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactPropTypeLocationNames.js 572 bytes {0} [built]
  [200] ./~/fbjs/lib/shallowEqual.js 1.74 kB {0} [built]
  [201] ./~/react-dom/lib/shouldUpdateReactComponent.js 1.4 kB {0} [built]
  [202] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactEmptyComponent.js 704 bytes {0} [built]
  [203] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactHostComponent.js 1.98 kB {0} [built]
  [204] ./~/react-dom/lib/getNextDebugID.js 437 bytes {0} [built]
  [205] ./~/react-dom/lib/KeyEscapeUtils.js 1.29 kB {0} [built]
  [206] ./~/react-dom/lib/traverseAllChildren.js 7.04 kB {0} [built]
  [207] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactElementSymbol.js 622 bytes {0} [built]
  [208] ./~/react-dom/lib/getIteratorFn.js 1.12 kB {0} [built]
  [209] ./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js 2.77 kB {0} [built]
  [210] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactServerRenderingTransaction.js 2.29 kB {0} [built]
  [211] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactServerUpdateQueue.js 4.83 kB {0} [built]
  [212] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactUpdateQueue.js 9.01 kB {0} [built]
  [213] ./~/react-dom/lib/validateDOMNesting.js 13.7 kB {0} [built]
  [214] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMEmptyComponent.js 1.9 kB {0} [built]
  [215] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMTreeTraversal.js 3.72 kB {0} [built]
  [216] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMTextComponent.js 5.82 kB {0} [built]
  [217] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js 1.88 kB {0} [built]
  [218] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactEventListener.js 5.3 kB {0} [built]
  [219] ./~/fbjs/lib/EventListener.js 2.67 kB {0} [built]
  [220] ./~/fbjs/lib/getUnboundedScrollPosition.js 1.05 kB {0} [built]
  [221] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactInjection.js 1.2 kB {0} [built]
  [222] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactReconcileTransaction.js 5.26 kB {0} [built]
  [223] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactInputSelection.js 4.27 kB {0} [built]
  [224] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMSelection.js 6.78 kB {0} [built]
  [225] ./~/react-dom/lib/getNodeForCharacterOffset.js 1.62 kB {0} [built]
  [226] ./~/fbjs/lib/containsNode.js 1.05 kB {0} [built]
  [227] ./~/fbjs/lib/isTextNode.js 605 bytes {0} [built]
  [228] ./~/fbjs/lib/isNode.js 693 bytes {0} [built]
  [229] ./~/fbjs/lib/getActiveElement.js 895 bytes {0} [built]
  [230] ./~/react-dom/lib/SVGDOMPropertyConfig.js 7.32 kB {0} [built]
  [231] ./~/react-dom/lib/SelectEventPlugin.js 6.06 kB {0} [built]
  [232] ./~/react-dom/lib/SimpleEventPlugin.js 7.97 kB {0} [built]
  [233] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticAnimationEvent.js 1.21 kB {0} [built]
  [234] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticClipboardEvent.js 1.17 kB {0} [built]
  [235] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticFocusEvent.js 1.07 kB {0} [built]
  [236] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticKeyboardEvent.js 2.71 kB {0} [built]
  [237] ./~/react-dom/lib/getEventCharCode.js 1.5 kB {0} [built]
  [238] ./~/react-dom/lib/getEventKey.js 2.87 kB {0} [built]
  [239] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticDragEvent.js 1.07 kB {0} [built]
  [240] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticTouchEvent.js 1.28 kB {0} [built]
  [241] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticTransitionEvent.js 1.23 kB {0} [built]
  [242] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticWheelEvent.js 1.94 kB {0} [built]
  [243] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js 25.5 kB {0} [built]
  [244] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMContainerInfo.js 967 bytes {0} [built]
  [245] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMFeatureFlags.js 439 bytes {0} [built]
  [246] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactMarkupChecksum.js 1.47 kB {0} [built]
  [247] ./~/react-dom/lib/adler32.js 1.19 kB {0} [built]
  [248] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactVersion.js 350 bytes {0} [built]
  [249] ./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js 2.46 kB {0} [built]
  [250] ./~/react-dom/lib/getHostComponentFromComposite.js 740 bytes {0} [built]
  [251] ./~/react-dom/lib/renderSubtreeIntoContainer.js 422 bytes {0} [built]
  [252] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMUnknownPropertyHook.js 4.32 kB {0} [built]
  [253] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMNullInputValuePropHook.js 1.37 kB {0} [built]
  [254] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMInvalidARIAHook.js 3.14 kB {0} [built]
  [255] ./client/components/Dashboard/Dashboard.js 3.68 kB {0} [built]
  [256] ./client/components/Dashboard/TopHeader.js 4.71 kB {0} [built]
  [257] ./client/components/Dashboard/Logo.js 3.38 kB {0} [built]
  [258] ./client/components/Dashboard/Sidebar.js 5.77 kB {0} [built]
  [259] ./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css 918 bytes {0} [built]
  [260] ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css 101 kB {0} [built]
  [261] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
  [262] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0 82 bytes {0} [built]
  [263] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot 82 bytes {0} [built]
  [264] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 84 bytes {0} [built]
  [265] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0 83 bytes {0} [built]
  [266] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0 82 bytes {0} [built]
  [267] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0 82 bytes {0} [built]
  [268] ./~/style-loader/addStyles.js 7.15 kB {0} [built]
  [269] ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 921 bytes {0} [built]
  [270] ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 357 kB {0} [built]
  [271] ./~/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot 82 bytes {0} [built]
  [272] ./~/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 84 bytes {0} [built]
  [273] ./~/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 83 bytes {0} [built]
  [274] ./~/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 82 bytes {0} [built]
  [275] ./~/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg 82 bytes {0} [built]
  [276] ./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js 267 kB {0} [built]
  [277] ./~/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js 484 bytes {0} [built]
  [278] ./~/bootstrap/js/transition.js 1.83 kB {0} [built]
  [279] ./~/bootstrap/js/alert.js 2.28 kB {0} [built]
  [280] ./~/bootstrap/js/button.js 3.82 kB {0} [built]
  [281] ./~/bootstrap/js/carousel.js 7.14 kB {0} [built]
  [282] ./~/bootstrap/js/collapse.js 5.99 kB {0} [built]
  [283] ./~/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js 4.74 kB {0} [built]
  [284] ./~/bootstrap/js/modal.js 9.99 kB {0} [built]
  [285] ./~/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js 16.7 kB {0} [built]
  [286] ./~/bootstrap/js/popover.js 3.16 kB {0} [built]
  [287] ./~/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js 4.71 kB {0} [built]
  [288] ./~/bootstrap/js/tab.js 3.9 kB {0} [built]
  [289] ./~/bootstrap/js/affix.js 4.84 kB {0} [built]
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Webpack configuration in `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./client/app.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/dist"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css?sourceMap'
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            }, 
            {
                 test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            }, 
            {
                 test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: "file"
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
            },
            { 
                test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, 
                loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' 
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery",
           jQuery: "jquery"
       })
    ],
    watch: true
  }
```

And here is my **React** code to render an icon:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

require('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css');
require('../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');

ReactDOM.render(
              <div>
              <a href="javascript:"><i className="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
              </div>,
  document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

The final result is a square in the screen, not the desired icon. I've tried several different icons with no success.

Help appreaciated to solve that.

Comment: "I've configured webpack properly" - can you provide your webpack config?

Comment: Sure, see edit...

Comment: Can you please show when the rest of your css is loading in relation to your font-awesome css? Can't see the load order. In general, load the fonts first, then the other styles and make sure these are available before the html is loaded.

Comment: Nathaniel, done. Check edited code.

Answer (score 4):

What is the expected behavior?
CSS property < font-family: FontAwesome !important > should be applied to font element by default (This CSS class is written in Font-Awesome.css file.) but due page or css load issue this property is not getting applied.

What went wrong?
font-family is set to different font family instead of font awesome.

Does it occur on multiple sites: Yes

Is it a problem with a plugin? No

Does this work in other browsers? Yes Safari

The issue appears at random, but seems to happen more often on complex CSS websites.

**Solution** :: add CSS property < font-family: FontAwesome !important > in your code explicitly in your code.

yourcssfile.css

```
.fa{
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
   }
```

Comment: Had the same problem on Symfony 4 with webpack. This solved my problem `.fa, .far, .fas {
  font-family: FontAwesome !important;
}` .

Very tiny amount of icons is not working - no idea why, but that's totally fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

as of 2021, this is how you set up font awesome in your react-webpack project:

`npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

in top main file of your project

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
```

in the component that you want to use the icon:

```
 <button className="button"    >
    <span className="icon">
      <i className="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>{" "}
    </span>
  </button>
```

you need two loaders, for woff file types, file loader, for svg , svg-url-loader

```
npm i svg-url-loader --save-dev
npm i file-loader --save-dev
```

in webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(ts|tsx)/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[contenthash].[ext]",
              outputPath: "fonts/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "svg-url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, before using [this](https://github.com/gowravshekar/font-awesome-webpack) package. After installing it, configure it in the `webpack.config.js` file like this:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // the url-loader uses DataUrls.
      // the file-loader emits files.
      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  }
};
```

Edit: [This](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-fa) one seems to be better ;)

Comment: The [react-fa](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-fa) package combined with [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) did the trick for me, although as a new comer to react+webpack I'm starting to get concerned about how many plugins and/or config I need to get something working..